# Is it possible for the forward and reverse reactions to have different reaction orders?

Tags: kinetics, adsorption

For example, in the case of non-dissociative adsorption, the rate of the forward process is given by

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} = kCN(1−\theta)$$

where $C$ is the concentration, $N$ is the number of surface sites, and $\theta$ is the fraction of filled sites.

The reverse reaction is given by

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} = −kN\theta.$$

Hence, it seems like the first reaction is second-order, while the second is first order. This seems strange to me.

Comment: But $\mathrm N$ is constant?

Comment: N is constant, but $\theta$ is not

Comment: The usage of `\ce` should be limited to typesetting chemicals and chemical equations - please don't use it to enclose mathematical expressions - these ought to be in italics.

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks! What does the \mathrm you used mean?

Comment: Math, **r**o**m**an type; i.e. no italics. In this case, it is only suitable for the $\mathrm{d}$ in differentials, which [should be upright](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/443/should-we-correct-math-formatting/444#444).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is this strange?

Consider:

$$\ce{2A <=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$] A_2}$$

Forward rate is second order: $k_1[\ce{A}]^{2}$.

Reverse rate is first order $k_{-1}[\ce{A2}]$.

Comment: IMHO it is very problematic to speak about 'the reaction order.' If you just say 'the order' of the reaction without specification *against what* the order is specified, this will lead to confusion very quickly. After all, there can be several reactants/products involved in the reaction. And _at equilibrium_ the order of the reaction and reverse reaction should be the same against every component, respectively.

Comment: It's not that bad when there's only one reactant, but yes, in general, we should specify the reaction order w.r.t. some reactant.